# Convert TIMESTAMP to date in hql

Tags: java, sql, hql

I have TIMESTAMP  and I want to convert it to Date format. I have tried with to_char method but it gives me an error that the format is not compatible. Plz help me with this.

This is the TIMESTAMP that I want to convert,

```
timestampCreated = 29-SEP-10 00.00.00.000000000
```

and I want it from

```
"dd-MM-yyyy"
```

this format. And I have tried with this,

```
to_char(ap.timestampCreated,'dd-MM-yyyy')
```

But it's not working. Plz help me. Thank you.

Comment: My feeling is that such a conversion should not be handled at the HSQL layer, but rather should be handled in Java, _or_ in your specific database.  You can easily make the transformation in either once you decide what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you  Tim Biegeleisen. But I have to covert it from hql because I have some conditions to check with that timestamp. And the data which comes from front end is from date format. But in DB I have timestamp format.  "to_char(ap.timestampCreated,'dd-MM-yyyy') between :dateFrom and :dateTo"

Comment: No, I don't think you should be handling this in HSQL.  Deal with it in your Java code then.

Comment: @Shantha I'm really not sure, it's just a wild guess, but can you try this once `to_char(to_date(ap.timestampCreated, 'YYYY-MM-DDbHH:MI:SS.ssssss'),'dd-MM-yyyy')`

Comment: Thank you  Raman Sahasi. Have founded it. It's in this way to_char(ap.timestampCreated,'dd-MM-yyyy') between :dateFrom and :dateTo

Answer (score 0):

timestampCreated = 29-SEP-10 00.00.00.000000000

new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(timestampCreated)